# How to use conditions in update/delete commands with Hanami::Repository?

Tags: hanami, hanami-model

Can't figure out how to update/delete records by conditions with Hanami::Repository.

For example, there are these tables: `users` and `clients`.
Users have:

- `deleted_at` column, for marking user as deleted
- `client_id` column, as foreign key on `clients` table

How can I update user by `id`, only if record not marked as deleted, and scoped by specific client?

Here is the pseudo code:

```
Users
  .joins(:clients)
  .where('clients.id = ?', client_id)
  .where(deleted_at: nil)
  .update(new_attributes)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it should works for your case

```
UserRepository.new.users
  .where(id: user_id, deleted_at: nil, client_id: client_id)
  .update(attributes)
```

gem versions:

> hanami-model (1.3)
>
> pg (1.1.4)

Answer (score 0):

Just expanding on [we138](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10831592/we138)'s answer:
Hanami uses [ROM](https://rom-rb.org) and [Sequel](https://sequel.jeremyevans.net/) under the hood for it's repositories.
If you have any doubts about how to add filters for your queries, you can always check the documentation for [Hanami repositories](https://guides.hanamirb.org/repositories/overview/), and for those gems.

Using the hanami repository, you could do this update as described by [we138](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10831592/we138):

```
UserRepository.new.users
  .where(id: user_id, deleted_at: nil, client_id: client_id)
  .update(attributes)
```

And that would return you the number of affected rows.
If you wish to update the entry using your filters and return the affected rows, you can use sequel directly:

```
Sequel::Model.db[:users]
  .where(id: user_id, deleted_at: nil, client_id: client_id)
  .returning
  .update(attributes)
```

You can find more information on how to filter queries using ROM and Sequel in the following links:
https://rom-rb.org/4.0/learn/sql/queries/
https://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/dataset_filtering_rdoc.html